# should missing fields in a POST request throw an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am writing a route for registering users. There are three required fields, name, email and password.

How should I handle a missing field ?

Like this ?

```
function(req, res) {

     if(!req.body.name || !req.body.email || !req.body.password) {

         res.status(400).json({
             "message": "All fields required"
         });
        return;

     }
}
```

Or should I throw an error and pass it to my error handler like this :

```
function(req, res, next) {

     if(!req.body.name || !req.body.email || !req.body.password) {

          return next(new Error('All fields required'));

     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a middleware to make sure your endpoints get what they are supposed to. Try [Express Validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator)

Include:

```
 var expressValidator = require('express-validator')
```

Then

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(expressValidator([])); // place after bodyParser
```

At your endpoint you can either check fields in body, params, or query separately like

```
  req.checkBody('age', 'Invalid Age').notEmpty().isInt(); //required integer
  req.checkBody('name', 'Invalid Name').notEmpty().isAlpha(); //required string
  req.checkBody('name', 'Invalid Name').isAlpha(); // not required but should be string if exists

  //for params use req.checkParams and for query req.checkQuery

 var errors = req.validationErrors();
  if (errors) {
    res.send(errors).status(400);
    return;
  }
```

Or you can define and use a schema in a separate file. Let's say userSignUp.js inside validationSchemas directory

```
module.exports = {
'name': { 
    optional: true,
    isLength: {
      options: [{ min: 3, max: 15 }],
      errorMessage: 'Must be between 3 and 15 chars long' 
    },
    errorMessage: 'Invalid Name'
  },
 'email': {
    notEmpty: true,
    isEmail: {
      errorMessage: 'Invalid Email'
    }
  },
  'password': {
    notEmpty: true,
    errorMessage: 'Invalid Password' // Error message for the parameter
  }
}
```

And at point of validation:

```
var userSignUpSchema = require('./validationSchemas/userSignUp.js);

req.checkBody(userSignUpSchema);
      if (req.validationErrors()) {
        res.send(errors).status(400);
        return;
      }
```

For every use case you can add another schema file and validate the fields

Answer (score 0):

For only validate if fields are empty, the best way is validate in the front. If you use HTML 5 it's possible to use `require` in the input, this way the form is not submmited. But, in javascript this is not problem too.

Comment: Front end validation is nice for the user, but NEVER rely on front end validation.  What if the request isn't coming from the form, but rather a malicious bot or programmer sending a curl request with a SQL Injection?

Comment: For the case proposet, this is not the case. The code as OP post, is valid only in case of empty values, and my answer explicity this.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the first option.  The second one may in fact crash your server if you don't have any error middleware (not sure about that though).  Even if you had error middleware it would probably default to returning 500 - 400 is the proper response.

Comment: Why would it crash the server ? I have an error handler at the end of my app.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I missed that the first time.... your error middleware should handle it.

I have done it both ways... by throwing errors that have a status and by responding immediately.  I like to reserve the error middleware for unexpected (500) errors - it also puts your expected errors in your handler which seems cleaner to me.  But both could work in theory.  The way you have it in this example probably isn't great since you're not communicating a status to your error middleware.

Answer (score 0):

For required fields, instead of checking with the server and loading it more, you can simply do it in your front end. There are multiple ways of doing it. In HTML, there is a [required](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) attribute which you can set to true and it does not submit the form until all these required fields are filled. 
To get more control over how the error is handled, you can verify the form using a form verification method on submitting it which checks for empty and/or invalid fields (Form validation). This can be done using jQuery, plain old JS, angular or whatever you'd like to use at the client side.
In case you want to keep it completely server side, the first option wherein you're checking for empty object attributes and returning an error JSON is how I'd do it.